# Why is my variable being updated?

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller, model, command, state

I'm writing a program that uses MVC and command pattern. In my concrete command class, I need to store the previous state of the model so that I can implement undo/redo functionality.

I store a reference to the model in the command object when it is created, and I store a reference to the state I need to keep:
this.prevState = model.getState();

Why is the data in the command object being updated when it changes in the model object? how can I store the data about the previous state in the model without it changing unless I tell it to in the command object?

Answer (score 0):

I think (Because I don't know what language are you using) that you are storing a reference (Like a pointer) which is like a mirror, you can see and modify what is referenced to because you are storing a direction. And some programing language this process is invisible (Javascript, Java...) so what I could look for (Again, Because I don't know what language are you using) is something that is called Creation by Copy or Initalization by Copy or Constructor by Copy (I'm from Spain so I don't know the exact translation), something like this:

```
var olderState = new State(stateToSave);
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy

It's very common you have to program the entire copy, if this is the case remember when making the constructor you can copy primitive ones, but other objects maybe need also a Constructor by Copy.

Hope it works for you!